# Return immutable string in Rust

Tags: string, rust

I'm looking at returning a string from a function in Rust, but the only option I see right now is to return `String`, which can be modified. While it isn't incorrect, I quite like the idea of returning some strings like error descriptions as immutable.

So is there any way for functions currently returning for example `Result<Something, String>` to actually return the error as immutable? Is it possible to enforce it in the type itself while still returning something `Str`-compatible? Or should I just stop worrying and always give back `String`s? (like most of the `std::io` functions do)

Comment: You should critically examine why you feel uneasy about returning a mutable type. In many OOP languages, one avoids returning references to mutable types because that creates aliasing of mutable objects and hence any caller can easily cause strange action-at-a-distance. But this is a non-issue in Rust since if you return a `String` you return ownership of it and it's statically guaranteed that there are no (other) references to it.

Comment: @delnan I like immutable strings in this situation because you cannot accidentally modify them yourself. Let's say someone that we're still talking about error handling and in the error path I do `some_processing(message); log(message);`. In python, java, haskell, etc. I'm sure the message has not been modified by `some_processing`. I can't say the same about rust. Even if local code has ownership, the first function can still mess it up.

Comment: @viraptor, you can, in fact, say the same about Rust. If `message` is a `String`, your code just won't compile because `message` will be moved into the function. If it is a slice, it is immutable, so you can't do anything dangerous with it. The only way for `some_processing()` to modify its argument is to pass it via a mutable reference: `some_processing(&mut message)`, and here you can easily see that `some_processing()` modifies its argument.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rust employs a concept of inherited mutability - that is, whether the given piece of data is mutable or not is determined by the owner of this piece. Hence if your piece of data is a regular owned structure, like `String`, you can't influence its mutability after you return it.

There is a kind of workaround, however. As Rust is value-based language, an instance of a structure with a single field of some type has exactly the same representation as just a value of that type, so you can create a wrapper for your type which does not expose its field directly but provides a getter which returns an immutable reference to that field:

```rust
struct ImmutableString(String);

impl ImmutableString {
    #[inline]
    fn get_ref(&self) -> &String { &self.0 }

    // or, even better:

    #[inline]
    fn as_slice(&self) -> &str { self.0.as_slice() }
}
```

Due to compiler optimizations this is a zero-cost wrapper and both methods are inlined away, but because these methods are the only way to interact with the structure internals, and they only returns immutable references, the value of such structure will be effectively immutable.

However, I'd argue that you don't really need all of this. Rust concepts of ownership and borrowing eliminate all of the problems you usually have with mutable data in languages like C or C++ or Java, so just be natural - if you're returning a `String`, you're giving up all your control over it, so let the caller decide what they want to do with it, there's no need for any restrictions.

Comment: Tuple-structs can still be destructured, but you can prevent this by using the visibility rules. The user can still call the methods on the struct but they can't destructure because they can't import the type name. PlayPen: http://is.gd/vrWTVO For some reason, the tuple-indexing syntax you used didn't work, so I had to destructure and capture by-ref in the `as_slice()` method.

Comment: @Logician, tuple structs need to make their inner field public as well for them to be accessible from outside their module. [See it yourself](http://is.gd/Su7dya). So, there is no need to do anything else. As for indexing syntax, I think there's a PR to Rust master on that but it is yet to be merged.

Comment: Can you show how to use this in practice, in addition to the trait implementation? What does some code look like that deals with strings and constructing strings? I'm new to Rust and the string "casting" is super-annoying.

Comment: @PetrusTheron have you seen the Rust book chapter on strings? https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch08-02-strings.html I think it has a lot of examples of how to work with strings and construct them. I'm afraid otherwise your question is too generic; if you can come up with some specific question, feel free to ask it as a separate question here on SO.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirMatveev "owned mutability" clicked for me.